# No module named 'keras.layers.core

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

```
from keras.models import Sequential
   from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
   from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
```

```
    ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-35-e0ce7722f83a> in <cell line: 2>()
     1 from keras.models import Sequential
----> 2 from keras.layers.core import Dense, Flatten
    3 from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.core'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
 manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

use Chat GPT the answer is

> The error indicates that the module keras.layers.core cannot be found, suggesting an issue with the       Keras installation or compatibility.
>
> As of Keras version 2.7.0 (the latest stable version as of my last update), the module organization has     changed, and keras.layers.core is no longer used. Instead, core layers like Dense and Flatten are directly    available under keras.layers.

Comment: Per the response, `keras.layers.core is no longer used, Instead, core layers like Dense and Flatten are directly available under keras.layers`, sounds like you're trying to run old code and you should change the import statement... Colab examples aren't always up to date and are not a replacement for official documentation